# Differences between CMakeCache.txt and CMakeVars.txt

Tags: build, cmake, cmake-gui

#### Context:

When I want to build a projet, there are usually `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeVars.txt` files that are created at a first stage, e.g. using `cmake-gui > configure`.

#### Questions:

1. What are the differences between these files and what are they used for?
2. If I have tweaked a lot of options within `cmake-gui`, which file should I safely backup in an other location (for copying it back later on in order to not spend much time figuring out which options I had checked...) before removing the `build/` directory contents (this directory normally includes these two files) if I want to start from a clean `build/` directory (which is sometimes needed) ?